# Error in nlevels(object) : argument "object" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I'm trying to change the default color values in the HairEyeColor package in R and keep getting the error in nlevels when I run this:

```
library(ggplot2)
hec = data.frame(HairEyeColor)
ggplot(hec,aes(Hair, Freq))+
geom_point(aes(colour = Eye))+
scale_color_manual(values = C("brown" = "chocolate4", "blue" = "blue3", 
"hazel" = "#663", "green" = "darkgreen"))
```

Any ideas on how I can get the eye colors to change to the identified colors?  What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at `levels(hec$Eye)` : R is case sensitive: Also use `c` not `C` , also make sure `#663` is a colour

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error is caused by you miss-typing the `value` vector with a capital C. Should be: `values = c()`

I have corrected it below:

```
library(ggplot2)
hec = data.frame(HairEyeColor)
ggplot(hec,aes(Hair, Freq))+
geom_point(aes(colour = Eye))+
scale_color_manual(values = c("brown" = "chocolate4", "blue"= "blue3", "hazel" = "#663", "green" = "darkgreen"))
```